# Significance of shortname in git

Tags: git, version-control

Can anyone please explain the significance of using a shortname in `git remote` commands? I have tried to explore about it everywhere but nowhere did I find a very reasonable answer.

I know that origin is the default shortname, but we can use a different shortname too. When we look at the command `git remote -v`, it lists all remote repositories with their shortnames. Please explain the significance of using each one of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This short name is a key to your actual remote location, So that if you have more than one remote location in your local repository, You do not need to type URL again and again e.g. if you have these remotes

origin http://github.com/proj
upstream http://github.com/proj2

then when you will push, you need to specify the remote where you want to push

> git push origin or git push upstream

So you can see it is more convenient here to write small names instead of full URL.

Comment: That's understood. But I have seen different shortnames for same git URL.
 [Click here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes#Adding_Remote_Repositories) to see an example for the same.

Answer (score 2):

The significance is that it is much more convenient to write `origin` instead of `ssh://git@somehost.com/some/repo.git` every time you want to interact with the remote.

Answer (score 1):

**git** is the common part of all git command.

Now the **remote** means your repository location.

Actually whatever you do using git, all things can be tracked in your local machine. Using **remote** you can tracked your coda/data in a server from where other(permitted) user can also pull/push his her code/data.

**For more details go through the link.**

**https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote**